# Populate column of html table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I don't have much experience with javascript, and this is a hobby project.

The table below lists a number of location names, and their distances from the first location. This is intended as a travel guide, to be looked up during a trip so that I can estimate how far is what coming next.

I want to expand its usefulness by adding a click event to each row (or an `<a></a>` tag somewhere), so that when I click a row:

1. Its value become zero;
2. The other values become distances from that point;

So the question is: what approach I could use to get the current value (as an argument to the `onclick`, I imagine) and replace the other values so that they are somehow "remembered" and I can go on clicking on other rows and they become the zero-reference of the distance table?

```
<table>
    <tr><th>local</th><th>distância</th></tr>

    <tr><td>Chuí/Chuy</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Coronilla</td><td>24</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Tereza</td><td>33</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta del Diablo</td><td>40</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Esmeralda</td><td>58</td></tr>
    <tr><td>El Cocal (camping)</td><td>66</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Castillos</td><td>74</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Aguas Dulces</td><td>84</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Valizas</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cabo Polonio (port.)</td><td>97</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oceania del Polonio</td><td>106</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Isabel</td><td>130</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Pedrera</td><td>133</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Arachania</td><td>137</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Paloma</td><td>142</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Rocha</td><td>156</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Condominio Chique</td><td>170</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Garzon</td><td>187</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Arenas de J. Ignacio</td><td>193</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jose Ignacio</td><td>195</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Monica</td><td>202</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Baln. Buenos Aires</td><td>210</td></tr>
    <tr><td>El Chorro</td><td>212</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Manantiales</td><td>214</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Blanca</td><td>215</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Barra</td><td>217</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta (los dedos)</td><td>228</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Ballena</td><td>242</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Chihuahua</td><td>247</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ocean Park</td><td>256</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Av. Americas Unidas<br/>(acesso Piriápolis)</td><td>257</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Negra</td><td>265</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Colorada</td><td>268</td></tr>
    <tr><td>San Francisco</td><td>270</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Piriápolis</td><td>275</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Hermosa</td><td>279</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Las Flores<br/>(camp. El Eden)</td><td>283</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bella Vista</td><td>286</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Baln. Solís</td><td>290</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cuchilla Alta</td><td>302</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Lucía del Este</td><td>306</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Tuna</td><td>308</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Costa Azul</td><td>317</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parque del Plata<br/>(camping del Parque)</td><td>322</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Atlántida</td><td>328</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Salinas<br/>(camping Albatros)<br/>(camping Playa Escondida)</td><td>355</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ciudad de la Costa<br/>(Montevideo)</td><td>350</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parque Roosevelt</td><td>355</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Carrasco</td><td>359</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Verde</td><td>364</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Buceo</td><td>369</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Pocitos</td><td>372</td></tr>
</table>
```

And if you're curious, this is the beautiful coast of Uruguay:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=z32qCUCL7tTQ.kOUOnp-ptcHw"
width="640" height="480"></iframe>
```

Pure javascript-based answers are preferred.

Comment: @Barmar I prefer javascript, but I could use jQuery as an alternative. Since I'll probably want to use this on the road, I was thinking of putting the html files in the filesystem so that I wouldn't depend on internet being available.

Comment: You can download jquery.js to your filesystem, so it's not dependent on the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a jQuery solution. Put the original distances in the `data-distance` attribute of each distance field. Then use this in the calculations, rather than the text of the fields.

```js
$("tr").click(function() {
  var thisRow = $(this);
  var thisValField = thisRow.find("td:nth-child(2)");
  var thisVal = thisValField.data("distance");
  thisValField.text("0");
  $(this).siblings().find("td:nth-child(2)").text(function() {
    var oldVal = $(this).data("distance");
    return Math.abs(thisVal - oldVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><th>local</th><th>distância</th></tr>

    <tr><td>Chuí/Chuy</td><td data-distance="0">0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Coronilla</td><td data-distance="24">24</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Tereza</td><td data-distance="33">33</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta del Diablo</td><td data-distance="40">40</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Esmeralda</td><td data-distance="58">58</td></tr>
    <tr><td>El Cocal (camping)</td><td data-distance="66">66</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Castillos</td><td data-distance="74">74</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Aguas Dulces</td><td data-distance="84">84</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Valizas</td><td data-distance="90">90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cabo Polonio (port.)</td><td data-distance="97">97</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oceania del Polonio</td><td data-distance="106">106</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Isabel</td><td data-distance="130">130</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Pedrera</td><td data-distance="133">133</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Arachania</td><td data-distance="137">137</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Paloma</td><td data-distance="142">142</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Rocha</td><td data-distance="156">156</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Condominio Chique</td><td data-distance="170">170</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Garzon</td><td data-distance="187">187</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Arenas de J. Ignacio</td><td data-distance="193">193</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Jose Ignacio</td><td data-distance="195">195</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Monica</td><td data-distance="202">202</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Baln. Buenos Aires</td><td data-distance="210">210</td></tr>
    <tr><td>El Chorro</td><td data-distance="212">212</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Manantiales</td><td data-distance="214">214</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Laguna Blanca</td><td data-distance="215">215</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Barra</td><td data-distance="217">217</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta (los dedos)</td><td data-distance="228">228</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Ballena</td><td data-distance="242">242</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Chihuahua</td><td data-distance="247">247</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ocean Park</td><td data-distance="256">256</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Av. Americas Unidas<br/>(acesso Piriápolis)</td><td data-distance="257">257</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Negra</td><td data-distance="265">265</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Punta Colorada</td><td data-distance="268">268</td></tr>
    <tr><td>San Francisco</td><td data-distance="270">270</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Piriápolis</td><td data-distance="275">275</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Hermosa</td><td data-distance="279">279</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Las Flores<br/>(camp. El Eden)</td><td data-distance="283">283</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bella Vista</td><td data-distance="286">286</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Baln. Solís</td><td data-distance="290">290</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cuchilla Alta</td><td data-distance="302">302</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Santa Lucía del Este</td><td data-distance="306">306</td></tr>
    <tr><td>La Tuna</td><td data-distance="308">308</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Costa Azul</td><td data-distance="317">317</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parque del Plata<br/>(camping del Parque)</td><td data-distance="322">322</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Atlántida</td><td data-distance="328">328</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Salinas<br/>(camping Albatros)<br/>(camping Playa Escondida)</td><td data-distance="355">355</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Ciudad de la Costa<br/>(Montevideo)</td><td data-distance="350">350</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Parque Roosevelt</td><td data-distance="355">355</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Carrasco</td><td data-distance="359">359</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Verde</td><td data-distance="364">364</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Buceo</td><td data-distance="369">369</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Playa Pocitos</td><td data-distance="372">372</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is interesting! But it has some mistake. If I keep clicking and clicking, the distances get more and more accumulated error, beind lower than they should. What do you thing of using an array to store the first values, and possibly a flag to tell if new recalculations should pick values from the table or from the array?

Comment: (I swear I would love to do this by myself, but the trip is coming, I'm in a hurry, and I suck at javascript/jquery...)

Comment: That's why I saved the old values in `.data("originalText")`.

Comment: Another solution is to put the original values in a `data` attribute in the original HTML. Then you don't have to save it each time, you can just use the data values.

Comment: Sorry if I made it look like that. I really want to learn, and I'm sure I could go on from here except it's jQuery. Anyway, I feel I could catch the gist of it and port it to javascript by myself, do you think it would be difficult? (I mean,  the jquery-to-javascript translation)?

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the `data-distance` attribute to hold the original distances.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems to work fine! I'll tinker with this solution a bit more, there's surely a lot of tricks to be learned here!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Barmar's answer, I came up with this pure javascript alternative:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function recalculate(event) {
        var thisRow = event.path[1];
        var distValue = thisRow.childNodes[1].innerHTML;

        for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
            var curDist = parseInt(row.cells[1].innerHTML)
            var newDist = curDist - distValue;
            row.cells[1].innerHTML = "" + newDist;
        };
    }

    var distances = []; 

    var table = document.getElementById("distanceTable");

    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        row.addEventListener('click', recalculate);
        var distance = parseInt(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
        distances.push(distance);
    }
</script>
```